# Angular 2 Multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

The following warning occurs during compilation:

> WARNING in ./src/app/state/actions/userClass.ts There are multiple
>   modules with names that only differ in casing. This can lead to
>   unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
>   case-semantic. Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>   * /Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/@angularclass/hmr-loader/index.js!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist/entry.js?{configFileName:
>   "tsconfig.webpack.json"}!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/angular2-template-loader/index.js!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/angular-router-loader/src/index.js?loader=system&genDir=compiled&aot=false!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/src/app/state/actions/UserClass.ts
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/@angularclass/hmr-loader/index.js!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist/entry.js?{configFileName:
>   "tsconfig.webpack.json"}!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/angular2-template-loader/index.js!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/angular-router-loader/src/index.js?loader=system&genDir=compiled&aot=false!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/src/app/features/portal/content/tabs/userclasses/userclasses.component.ts
>   * /Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/@angularclass/hmr-loader/index.js!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist/entry.js?{configFileName:
>   "tsconfig.webpack.json"}!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/angular2-template-loader/index.js!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/angular-router-loader/src/index.js?loader=system&genDir=compiled&aot=false!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/src/app/state/actions/userClass.ts
>       Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
>       /Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/@angularclass/hmr-loader/index.js!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist/entry.js?{configFileName:
>   "tsconfig.webpack.json"}!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/angular2-template-loader/index.js!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/node_modules/angular-router-loader/src/index.js?loader=system&genDir=compiled&aot=false!/Users/smp/Projects/training3/src/app/state/effects/userClass.ts

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The names of my files where fine.  This issue popped up because in one of my imports I capitalized UserClass:

```
import * as userClassActions from '../../../../../state/actions/UserClass';
```

After changing the import to the following the error went away:

```
import * as userClassActions from '../../../../../state/actions/userClass';
```

Comment: this was it - I had 'Events.service' instead of 'events.service' on an import.

Answer (score 12):

I was getting the same error because of a mistake I did while writing import.

Check if you've written somewhere --> **import { RouterModule } from '@angular/Router';**

Now, change it to --> **import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';**

This solved my problem. Hope it works for you too.

See the images below for more clarity

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS1nh.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyDGs.png

Comment: I had the same issue: in my case  I was importing **rxjs** in my application, and for some of the imports I had made a mistake to capitalize R  as **Rxjs**

Answer (score 3):

If you are coding with **Visual Studio Code**, it may happen that it will sometimes add path with capital letter and other times with a lower letter.

In my case I was getting the error because of *Angular Material* components were imported from `'@angular/material'` in some files and in (at least 2) other files from `'@angular/Material'`.

Lower-casing `'@angular/Material'` removed the warning.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue while implementing angular 4 App with asp.net core 2.0 and web pack.

This issue can occur if you import service or class with two different "./" or "../" relative path notation.

Import code in NavMenuComponent.

```
import { SampleService } from '../../services/sample.service';
```

Changing with following code the error was resolved

```
import { SampleService } from './../../services/sample.service';
```

[Learn more about GitHub discussion](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/issues/234)

Answer (score 0):

check if you have imported twice.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by entries in your webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development'
  , entry: {
    crm: './Scripts/app/crm/crm.router.js'
    , labels: './Scripts/app/labels/labels.router.js'
    , admin: './scripts/app/crm/admin/admin.router.js'
  }
  , output: {
    filename: '[name]Bundle.js'
    , path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
///...
};
```

Notice the casing of **scripts** vs **Scripts** in the entry section.

Answer (score 0):

I got that warning **after renaming the file** to upper case intentionally.

After **moving the specific file into another folder and back to the original** the warning was gone.

(I use VSC with some angular extensions that do the updating of imports when moving files)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that, and the solution was to create one subfolder in which you put your problem component.

So instead of:

```
import {EventsComponent} from './Shared/Components/events/events.component';
```

Do something like:

```
import {EventsComponent} from './Shared/Components/About Event/events/events.component';
```

Answer (score 0):

One of annoying possible cause of the problem: mixed upper and lowercases in components path - make it same. For example,

```
import {EventsComponent} from './events/events.component';
import {OtherComponent} from './Events/other.component';
```